# Passwords validation using jquery form validation jquery.form-validator.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am using following code where I need to match the passwords inside a form. It doesn't work on most of helps provided on here and other websites. I could have missed something that I am unable to trace. Please help me with this.

HTML

```
<form id="user_form" class='has-validation-callback'>
<input type="password" name="pass_confirmation" class="form-control" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="min6">
<input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" class="form-control" data-validation-confirm="confirmation" data-validation-help="Please give us some more information">
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
$.validate({
    modules : 'security',
    form : '#user_form',
    onError : function() {
        alert('Sorry! Please complete the form fields.');
    }
});
```

Link to library

```
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.3.19/jquery.form-validator.js
```

Comment: It doesn't show error if passwords are different.

Comment: After two years, this bug still exists :(

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [password confirmation](http://www.formvalidator.net/#security-validators_confirmation)

> This validator can be used to validate that the values of two inputs are the same. The first input should have a name suffixed with _confirmation and the second should have the same name but without the suffix.

```
<input type="password" name="pass_confirmation" class="form-control" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="min6">
<input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" class="form-control" data-validation="confirmation" data-validation-help="Please give us some more information">
```

for the second input change attribute `data-validation-confirm="confirmation"` to `data-validation="confirmation"` it will work.

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/murli2308/dqwagj55/)

Comment: Nope! Doesn't work. Error: Using undefined validator "validate_confirmation". Maybe you have forgotten to load the module that "validate_confirmation" belongs to?

Comment: are you using latest version ? `<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.3.19/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Yes that's what I have added in the question. Also I tried to solve using 2.2.43 version.

Comment: added fiddle check it is working. may be wrong with your jquery version or check sytax once again

Answer (score 0):

Try using a newer version of the library as it seems there may be a bug. 
I was using the same version you had listed and received the same error. https://github.com/victorjonsson/jQuery-Form-Validator/issues/479